# Multiple DataGrids with overall scroll

Tags: c#, wpf

This is what I would like achieve. I will explain below.

[image]

I have multiple grids and I would like a little of each grid shown. Basically, each `DataGrid` should take up the same amount of the screen, with a `GridSplitter` between to resize. There is a minimum size so if the screen is small there will be an overall scroll too.

How can I achieve this?

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid />
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" />
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="3" Height="5" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="4" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This without the `ScrollViewer` works until the size of the screen gets small, then you can't see all the `DataGrid`s. If I add the `ScrollViewer` in, then the `DataGrid`s show all results, and there is one gigantic scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Unfortunately, it's all in code.

The xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid />
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" />
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="3" Height="5" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="4" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Wire up some events:

```
scrollViewer.Loaded += ScrollViewerLoaded;
scrollViewer.SizeChanged += ScrollViewerElementSizeChanged;
```

Do some resizing:

```
private void ScrollViewerLoaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    if( grid != null && scrollViewer != null && 
        grid.ActualHeight > scrollViewer.ActualHeight )
    {
        if( grid.RowDefinitions.Count < 2 )
        {
            return;
        }

        // If the Grid is larger than the ScrollViewer, set the
        // Grids row sizes evenly.
        var rowDefinitions = grid.RowDefinitions.ToList();
        for( var i = 0; i < rowDefinitions.Count; i += 2 )
        {
            var rowDefinition = rowDefinitions[i];
            rowDefinition.Height = new GridLength( 200 );
        }
    }
}

private void ScrollViewerElementSizeChanged( object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e )
{
    if( grid.RowDefinitions.Count < 2 )
    {
        return;
    }

    var totalHeight = grid.RowDefinitions.Sum( rd => rd.ActualHeight );
    if( totalHeight < grid.ActualHeight )
    {
        // If the Grids total row heights are less than the height
        // of the Grid, adjust the last row height so they are equal.
        var lastRow = grid.RowDefinitions.Last();
        var otherRowsHeight = totalHeight - lastRow.ActualHeight;
        var newHeight = grid.ActualHeight - otherRowsHeight;
        lastRow.Height = new GridLength( newHeight );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a `MinHeight` and a `MaxHeight` for the Grids.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="200" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="200" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="200" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid2" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}"                          
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid3" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding}"                          
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And for GridSplitters, add `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`.

But still has an issue- the ScrollBars of the DataGrid does not show up until you drag the Splitter.

Comment: Putting an explicit `MaxHeight` in there will not allow them to be big when the window is maximized. Also, I updated my `GridSplitter` attributes to be more accurate to what I'm actually doing.